# Can anyone list what are the different types of automation testing could be used to test web application in mobile devices

Tags: testing, web-applications, automation, protractor, mobile-devices

I have done automation for web application using protractor. Now, I need to test the same in mobile device. Could anyone suggest me which tool can be used to test? I have gone through Appium. apart from it, is there any testing tools that could be used to test the protractor script in mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use Jasmine and karma for testing your application.

http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-your-ionic-app-part-1/
https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-unit-test-an-ionic-2-application/